# How to search through html for youtube and vimeo videos with php

Tags: php, regex, full-text-search, youtube, vimeo

I need some way to search through lots of HTML for youtube and vimeo videos. Some of the text uses the iframe type of embed where others uses the embed tag. I need to do the following:

Search for embed tags
- check if they're youtube or vimeo

search for iframe tags
- check if they're youtube or vimeo

I then want to take input them into an array as following:

```
array(type=>'youtube', video_id=>'12qfsdf9jr');
```

or for vimeo

```
array(type=>'vimeo', video_id=>'lkaj82932');
```

If it makes a difference, it's going to be searching through a HUGE amount of wordpress posts. Please let me know how I can accomplish this!

Comment: It would probably be easiest to loop through all URLs found on a page, then try to match the URLs and remove duplicates. Embed codes change too readily to write a reliable regex for them.

Comment: Ok. well to narrow it down even more, I know that embeds and iframes always have the src="url" in them how could I do a search for src= and then just take the URL from that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). The entry "How to get HTML elements?" in the Quickstart section looks pretty close to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com");

preg_match_all("/src=(?:\"|\')(.*?)(?:\"|\'))/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match){
    $data = parse_url($match[1]);
    if($data['host'] == 'youtube.com'){
        //do stuff. $data['query'] will have the video ID in it
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is optimized for speed. It parses Vimeo and YouTube videos separately, which allows using a fast regex for each (with exposed literal text at the pattern start which triggers PCRE optimizations.) Also, a slightly different array format is used to store the data where the video clip ID is stored as the array key, and the video type (either "vim" or "yt") as the value. This ensures no duplicate entries are added. Here is a tested script which does the trick:

```php
// Store videos as: array('vimeo_id' => 'vim', 'youtube_id' => 'yt' );
// This ensures no duplicate entries are added to $videos array.
$videos = array();  

// Find all unique Vimeo videos
$re_vimeo = '%vimeo\.com/(\d{7,9})\b%';
$count = preg_match_all($re_vimeo, $data, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $videos[$matches[1][$i]] = 'vim';
}
$vimeo_count = count($videos);

// Find all unique YouTube videos
$re_youtube = '%youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?v=|embed/)(\w{10,12})\b%';
$count = preg_match_all($re_youtube, $data, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $videos[$matches[1][$i]] = 'yt';    // Add only unique videos to array.
}
$total_count = count($videos);
$youtube_count = $total_count - $vimeo_count;
printf("%d Unique videos found. Vimeo count = %d, YouTube count = %d\n",
     $total_count, $vimeo_count, $youtube_count);print_r($videos);
```

Comment: the vimeo one doesn't seem to pick up all the videos. i have 64 matches in the database but on 32 in the array. Maybe it's not picking up all the ways of embedding?

Comment: oh i see what it's doing. it's just searching for vimeo.com/video_id. It can't do that because it just picks up all the links on the site. none of the actually embeds. any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of a vimeo embed string which is not matched? I'll be glad to update the solution.